# Trying to search in a model via eloquent - laravel with optimal parameters

Tags: php, laravel, search, eloquent

Im trying to figure out why my query is ignoring everything except the title and the description. The search button leading to the controller, is for filtering different type of ads , by category, by region, by price. 
For example if now i search for existing ad and its found by title / keyword -> will always show, even if i choose a different region / category/ price range

Im trying to use something that will save me a lot of if statements to check if they exist in the request. Maybe other option si to use https://github.com/mohammad-fouladgar/eloquent-builder to build my query

```php
 public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $keyword = $request['keyword'];
        $category_id = $request['category_id'];
        $type_id = $request['type_id'];
        $region_id = $request['region_id'];
        $min_price = $request['min_price'];
        $max_price = $request['max_price'];


        $result = Ad::when($keyword, function ($q) use ($keyword) {
            return $q->where('title', 'like', '%' . $keyword . '%')->orWhere('description', 'like', '%' . $keyword . '%');
        })
            ->when($category_id, function ($q) use ($category_id) {
                return $q->where('category_id', $category_id);
            })
            ->when($region_id, function ($q) use ($region_id) {
                return $q->where('region_id', '=', $region_id);
            })
            ->when($type_id, function ($q) use ($type_id) {
                return $q->where('adtype_id', '=', $type_id);
            })
            ->when($min_price, function ($q) use ($min_price) {
                return $q->where('price', '>=', $min_price);
            })
            ->when($max_price, function ($q) use ($max_price) {
                return $q->where('price', '<=', $max_price);
            })
            ->paginate(8);
```

My get param url looks like that: 
search?keyword=&category_id=0&region_id=0&type_id=0&min_price=&max_price=

The produced query in mysql when i search for existing ad by its name and i look for a different category is:

```
select * from `ads` where `title` like '%test test%' or `description` like '%test test%' and `category_id` = '2' limit 8 offset 0
```

The ad is found, but the actual category is 1, not 2, same for all others optimal parameters.

Comment: Are all of your queries (category, region, type) relations, or that's contained in single table?

Comment: All of them are related, but the id-s are in the current table, yes

Comment: So for example, Ad belongsTo / has category?

Comment: Yes, category, condition, region , they are related via belongsTo

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your query to look for specific relations, using `whereHas`. This method will allow you to add customized constraints to a relationship constraint, such as checking the content of a comment.And to check max/min price, use `where` method. So, you can use it like this:

```
$result = Ad::when($keyword, function ($q) use ($keyword) {
            return $q->where('title', 'like', '%' . $keyword . '%')->orWhere('description', 'like', '%' . $keyword . '%');
        })
            ->whereHas('category_relation_name', function ($q) use ($category_id) {
                return $q->where('category_id', $category_id);
            })
            ->whereHas('region_relation_name', function ($q) use ($region_id) {
                return $q->where('region_id', $region_id);
            })
            ->whereHas('type_relation_name', function ($q) use ($type_id) {
                return $q->where('adtype_id', $type_id);
            })
            ->where('price', '>=', $min_price);
            ->where('price', '<=', $max_price);
            ->paginate(8);
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for the answer. Im getting ` InvalidArgumentException
Illegal operator and value combination.` .  Most likely because the $request of the other optimal params are null,

Comment: My bad, edited the answer, forgot to remove " = " sign

Comment: Thanks, i removed them too - to test - same thing .Is that proofed safe against null variables from the $request?

Comment: `select count(*) as aggregate from `ads` where `title` like '%test%' or `description` like '%test%' and exists (select * from `categories` where `ads`.`category_id` = `categories`.`id` and `category_id` = '0') and exists (select * from `regions` where `ads`.`region_id` = `regions`.`id` and `region_id` = '0') and exists (select * from `ad_types` where `ads`.`adtype_id` = `ad_types`.`id` and `adtype_id` = '0') and `price` >= 10 and `price` <= 50` Thats the produced query, when im trying to  search. i made (int) to the $req min and max price, so it fixed the  illegal operation error

Comment: Seems like your request passed, but all your values are 0. Check your form, maybe you got something wrong there.

Comment: Does that requre to have them with actual relationship in the sql, $tabe->reference() , and such? because i only used eloquent to relate them, not added anything special in the migrations . I fixed the query params thing, but the result is the same